# Bucle do while C

Tags: c

Intento realizar este bucle "do while" donde si el usuario introduce la palabra "TERMINAR" salga del bucle y siga el código hasta el final y si pone la palabra "SEGUIR" siga introduciendo datos pero no lo consigo resolver:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "listasDinamicas.h"

int main()
{

    lista listaEntreno;
    tipoelementolista ejercicio;

    listaVacia(&listaEntreno); // Lista Vaciada

    char condicion[8];

    do
    {

        printf("Introduzca el nombre del ejercicio: ");
        scanf("%s", ejercicio.nomEjer);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Introduzca el numero de series: ");
        scanf("%d", &ejercicio.numSeries);

        printf("Introduzca el numero de repeticiones: ");
        scanf("%d", &ejercicio.numRepes);

        printf("Introduzca el peso: ");
        scanf("%f", &ejercicio.peso);

        printf("Introduzca el dia: ");
        scanf("%d", &ejercicio.fechaHaltero.dia);
        printf("Introduzca el mes: ");
        scanf("%d", &ejercicio.fechaHaltero.mes);
        printf("Introduzca el anno: ");
        scanf("%d", &ejercicio.fechaHaltero.anno);

        insertarLista(&listaEntreno, ejercicio);
        printf("¿Desea Introducir otro ejercio? TERMINAR O SEGUIR: ");
        scanf("%s", condicion);

    } while (strcmp(condicion, "SEGUIR") == 0);

    int contadorPesoMuerto = 0;
    while (!esVaciaLista(listaEntreno))
    {
        primero(listaEntreno, &ejercicio);
        if (strcmp(ejercicio.nomEjer, "peso muerto") == 0 || (ejercicio.nomEjer, "PESO MUERTO") == 0 || (ejercicio.nomEjer, "Peso muerto") == 0)
        {

            contadorPesoMuerto++;
        }
        if (ejercicio.peso > 100)
        {
            printf("En el ejercicio %s has realizado %d series con un numero de repeticiones de %d cuyo peso ha sido %f kg a fecha de %d/%d/%d"), ejercicio.nomEjer, ejercicio.numSeries, ejercicio.numRepes, ejercicio.peso, ejercicio.fechaHaltero.dia, ejercicio.fechaHaltero.mes, ejercicio.fechaHaltero.anno;
        }
        resto(listaEntreno, &ejercicio);
    }

    printf("El numero de veces que se ha frealizado peso muerto es de %d"), contadorPesoMuerto;
}
```

---

el error viene en la linea 14 hasta la 40
Este archivo va unido a un .h pero no lo he adjuntado ya que para el bucle do while no lo veo necesario porfavor estaría muy agradecido si me ayudarais.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error?

Comment: Que es `lista listaEntreno;`

Comment: `TERMINAR` necesita un array de tamaño 9, si no dejas espacio para el terminador de cadena `\0` estarás sobreescribiendo memoria de otras variables con resultados indeterminados